# How access to a element in a Multidimensional Array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I maybe missing something obvious but looking to access an element within a multidimensional array.

When I do the following

```
$rows = get_field('lineup_days_and_stages');
print_r($rows);
```

This is my array. How do I access the value in `stage_headliner` > `post_name`, so in this example it would be `Slipknot`

I tried the following and some variants but nowhere fast

```
foreach($rows as $value){
     if (isset($value["stage_headliner"]){
            echo $value["stage_headliner"][0]->post_name;
     }
}
```

The Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [stage_name] => Main Stage
            [stage_date] => 12/06/2015
            [stage_headliner] => Array
                (
                    [0] => WP_Post Object
                        (
                            [ID] => 36074
                            [post_author] => 1
                            [post_date] => 2002-05-15 12:54:20
                            [post_date_gmt] => 2002-05-15 12:54:20
                            [post_content] => 
                            [post_title] => Slipknot
                            [post_excerpt] => 
                            [post_status] => publish
                            [comment_status] => closed
                            [ping_status] => closed
                            [post_password] => 
                            [post_name] => slipknot
                            [to_ping] => 
                            [pinged] => 
                            [post_modified] => 2002-05-15 12:54:20
                            [post_modified_gmt] => 2002-05-15 12:54:20
                            [post_content_filtered] => 
                            [post_parent] => 0
                            [guid] => http://localhost/wordpress/artist/slipknot/
                            [menu_order] => 0
                            [post_type] => artist
                            [post_mime_type] => 
                            [comment_count] => 0
                            [filter] => raw
                        )

                )

                    ...
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Already asked it - how would I access the post_name

Comment: your code looks fine:
foreach($rows as $value){
     if (isset($value["stage_headliner"]){
            echo $value["stage_headliner"][0]->post_name;
     }
}

Comment: Sorry no, I just get a blank screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access to your value you need this:

```
echo $array[0]["stage_headliner"][0]->post_name;
```

If you have multiples *stage_headliners* (as you ask in your comment) you can do this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array[0]["stage_headliner"]); $i++) {
  echo $array[0]["stage_headliner"][$i]->post_name;
}
```

If you have multiples elements in your array you can do this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
  echo $array[$i]["stage_headliner"][0]->post_name;
}
```

Comment: How about if I had multiple stage headliners? How would I get $array[0]["stage_headliner"][1]->post_name;, $array[2]["stage_headliner"][0]->post_name;, $array[3]["stage_headliner"][0]->post_name; etc

Comment: @pee2pee just give me a minute ;-)

Comment: Close but I needed $array[1]["stage_headliner"][0],$array[2]["stage_headliner"][0] but managed to figure it all out in the end! Many many thanks

Comment: @pee2pee a pleasure and gook luck ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can just access the post_name directly in a multidimensional array.

In your case, you will have to do the following to get stage_headliner > post_name ($array is your multidimensional array):

```
echo $array[0]["stage_headliner"][0]->post_name;
```

This should print the output: slipknot

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Sorry no, I just get a blank screen

Comment: sorry, your post_name is located inside an object, therefore it should be: echo $array[0]["stage_headliner"][0]->post_name;